# update canvas element with a DOM canvas

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, html5-canvas

let's say I have

```
var myCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
```

and I do

```
myCanvas.setAttribute("id", "my-canvas");
document.body.appendChild(myCanvas);
```

Afterwords I make change to `myCanvas` and want to *replace* the html-canvas with my updated `DOM` canvas. The following works:

```
document.getElementById("my-canvas").innerHTML = myCanvas;
```

but the html (via inspector) looks like

```
<canvas id="my-canvas">[object HTMLCanvasElement]</canvas>
```

When it should look like

```
<canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>
```

How can I update the element and not use `innerHTML`?

Comment: At best, that approach would give you a canvas inside another canvas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to update `myCanvas` *if it is still the same node*. When you create a node and you append it do the DOM then the DOM node is *live*. It means that all changes on the `myCanvas` will be immediately reflected in the page.

#### replaceChild()

In case you want to replace a node with *different* node you can use [`.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.replaceChild) on the parent element of the node you want to replace.

*Example:*

```
document.getElementById("parent").replaceChild(element, newElement);
```

Where `parent` is the parent element of `element`.

```
<div id="parent">
  <canvas id="element"></canvas>
</div>
```

#### innerHTML

In your question you are using [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.innerHTML). If you want just to replace a content of one element by a content of another element, then use `innerHTML` on both of them.

*Example:*

```
document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = newElement.innerHTML;
```