# Is it possible to create a larger image object by pasting many smaller images together?

Tags: reactjs, image, canvas

I'm creating a React and Redux based game where the user must control a kingdom and give plots of land to nobles.

I've created a game map component which uses a canvas element to draw the game map. The game map is made out of many smaller tiles which represent plots of land. Currently I'm using request animation frame to draw the matrix of tiles. The user can also drag and drop, and zoom in and out of the map. The problem is the game map is actually quite laggy, since every frame it draws each tile, then draws borders, etc.

My question is this: is it possible to paste together each individual tile into a larger image so that I only have to draw one large image instead of iterating through the matrix of map data and drawing each individual tile every frame.

Its probably not necessary for you to see my current code, but here is my constructor and my drawGame function:

```
class MapPage extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.FieldImage = new Image()
    this.RockImage = new Image()
    this.PlainImage = new Image()
    this.HouseImage = new Image()
    this.Trees = new Image()
    this.GoldOre = new Image()
    this.ChurchBot = new Image()
    this.ChurchTop = new Image()
    this.BlueSpearman = new Image()

    this.FieldImage.src = Field
    this.RockImage.src = Rock
    this.PlainImage.src = Plain
    this.HouseImage.src = House
    this.Trees.src = Trees
    this.GoldOre.src = GoldOre
    this.ChurchBot.src = ChurchBot
    this.ChurchTop.src = ChurchTop
    this.BlueSpearman.src = BlueSpearman

    //mapOffset is in the redux store so that it persists when the user navigates away and navigates back
    this.state = {
      tileInfoIsVisible: true, //Currently this is always true, might change later
      mouseOffset: {},
      mouseX: 0,
      mouseY: 0,
      tileX: 0,
      tileY: 0,
    }
  }
```

```
drawGame(ctx, currentSecond = 0, framesLastSecond = 0, frameCount = 0) {
    if(ctx===null) return

    ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, viewportWidth, viewportHeight) //creates a black background

    let sec = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000)
    if(sec !== currentSecond){
      currentSecond = sec
      framesLastSecond = frameCount
    }

    const xOffset = this.props.mapOffset.x
    const yOffset = this.props.mapOffset.y
    const tileSize = this.props.tileSize

    for(let x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++){
      for(let y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++){
        //Always draw a plain image first on every tile, as a backdrop
        ctx.drawImage(this.PlainImage, x*tileSize + xOffset, y*tileSize + yOffset, tileSize, tileSize)
        switch(this.props.gameMap[x][y].type){
          case 'plain': //Not necessary to draw anything here, since plain is drawn on every time anyway
            //ctx.drawImage(this.PlainImage, x*tileSize, y*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize)
          break

          case 'rock':
            ctx.drawImage(this.RockImage, x*tileSize + xOffset, y*tileSize + yOffset, tileSize, tileSize)
          break

          case 'field':
            ctx.drawImage(this.FieldImage, x*tileSize + xOffset, y*tileSize + yOffset, tileSize, tileSize)
          break

          case 'house':
            ctx.drawImage(this.HouseImage, x*tileSize + xOffset, y*tileSize + yOffset, tileSize, tileSize)
          break

          case 'trees':
            ctx.drawImage(this.Trees, x*tileSize + xOffset, y*tileSize + yOffset, tileSize, tileSize)
          break

          case 'goldOre':
            ctx.drawImage(this.GoldOre, x*tileSize + xOffset, y*tileSize + yOffset, tileSize, tileSize)
          break

          case 'church':
            ctx.drawImage(this.ChurchBot, x*tileSize + xOffset, y*tileSize + yOffset, tileSize, tileSize)
            ctx.drawImage(this.ChurchTop, x*tileSize + xOffset, y*tileSize + yOffset - tileSize, tileSize, tileSize)
          break

          default:
        }

        switch(this.props.gameMap[x][y].kingdomOwner){
          case this.props.mainKingdom.id:
          ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(51, 153, 255, 0.3)'
          ctx.fillRect(x*tileSize + xOffset, y*tileSize + yOffset, tileSize, tileSize)
          this.drawKingdomBorder(x, y, this.props.mainKingdom, ctx)
          break

          default:
        }
      }
    }

    this.drawHoveredTileOutline(ctx)
    this.handleTileInfoCoordinates()
    if(window.location.pathname==='/newMap'){ // this is to stop the animation loop when the user navigates away from the page
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {this.drawGame(ctx)})
    }
  }
```

You can see that there is a lot going on every frame, which makes the game quite laggy, especially if the map is large

Comment: You may want to take a look at this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380411/update-canvas-element-with-a-dom-canvas
I don't have much experience with canvas, but I do know that it's generally faster to perform many updates to an element that is not part of the DOM, then insert the element into the DOM in a single step, than it is to perform many updates to an element that is already part of the DOM. I think it would also be worth investigating ways to only redraw tiles that need to be redrawn. React's built-in diffing may be useful here.

Comment: If you haven't read this, I think it will be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas